# Search inside lightning-dual-listbox in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a component with a lightning-dual-listbox. I need to make a search function for the available items. The user searchs and only the matching items are going to be displayed.

This is the code:

```
 <!-- DUELING PICKLIST -->
<lightning-layout-item flexibility="auto" padding="around-small">
  <p><font style="font-weight: bold;">Select Users (Required)<font style="color:red;">*</font></font></p>
  <div class="custom-box slds-box slds-p-around_medium slds-text-align_center">
    <lightning-dual-listbox label="" source-label="Available" selected-label="Selected" options={options} value={values} class="slds-p-top_medium" onchange={handleChange}>
    </lightning-dual-listbox>
  </div>
</lightning-layout-item>
<!-- END DUELING PICKLIST -->
```

How it looks:

[image]

Is it possible to search inside the picklist?

Best Regards,
Renato

Comment: please make sure to include what you have tried, and where you are stuck, rather than asking how to "do something". For example, your code does not demonstrate any research or attempt to filter values that you are loading into the dual-box component. maybe you can guide us through your attempt to doing so? and indicate where you are having issues?

Comment: Sorry for not deliver more details on this case. There is a lot of demand on this component of role hierarchy and this search is a new one demand. I don't know how to evolve on that. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by keeping track of the already-selected values as a separate value, or preserving the options that are currently selected. I wrote this [example](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/8TYMMoluMNEn2DPVYYJN/src/app.js?p=stories) and this [other example](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/0JCaZjR6WyPZDvdIjPpc/src/app.js?p=stories) for you.

In the first example, we make sure that selected values are always present in the list, thus preserving any selected entries regardless of filter:

```
  filter(event) {
    let filter = event? 
      new RegExp(this.template.querySelector('lightning-input').value, 'ig'):
      { test: function() { return true }}
    const selected = new Set(this.selected)
    this.options = this.allOptions.filter(option => (filter.test(option.value) || selected.has(option.value)))
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.selected = [...event.target.value]
    this.filter(true)
  }
```

In the second example, we preserve the selected values in a separate variable, thus ensuring we can restore those values when the filter is changed.

```
  filter(event) {
    const optToVal = (option) => option.value
    let filter = ''
    if(event) {
      filter = event.target.value
    }
    filter = new RegExp(filter, 'ig');
    this.options = this.allOptions.filter(option => filter.test(option.value))
    const shownOptions = new Set(this.options.map(optToVal))
    this.selected = this.allSelected.filter(selected => shownOptions.has(selected))
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    const optToVal = (option) => option.value
    const shownOptions = new Set(
      this.options.map(optToVal)
    )
    const hiddenOptions = new Set(
      this.allOptions.map(optToVal).filter(value => !shownOptions.has(value))
    )
    const hiddenSelected = this.allSelected.filter(value => hiddenOptions.has(value))
    const shownSelected = event.target.value
    this.allSelected = [...shownSelected, ...hiddenSelected]
  }
```

Feel free to use whichever form you prefer.

Comment: It Worked!! Thank you very much @sfdcfox !